# Cleanup directories in bash with rm -rf with escaped wildcard

Tags: bash

I am trying to cleanup some dir with this script.

It echoes the `"removing from"` lines but exits without removing the files.

I escaped the wildcard as needed for the shell to expand it.

I run it from sudo shell session.

Also I don't see any errors.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    declare -a paths=(      "OpsCenter/rollups300"
                            "OpsCenter/rollups60"
                            "table_a"
                            "table_b"
                            "table_c"
                            "table_d")

    for del_path in "${paths[@]}"
    do
            full_path="/var/lib/cassandra/data/$del_path/"
            echo "removing from" $full_path
            rm -rf "$full_path"/*
    done
```

**EDIT:**

After changing to `rm -rv "$full_path"/*`, I get the output

```
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/cassandra/data/table_a/*': No such file or directory
```

After I added the

```
ls -all "$full_path"\*
```

to the loop, the output of the `ls` command is also

```
cannot access `/var/lib/cassandra/data/table_a/*': No such file or directory
```

though the `ls` command with the same path when run from the command line does show there are files there.

```
    ls -all /var/lib/cassandra/data/table_a/*

    /var/lib/cassandra/data/table_a/draft_msg:
    total 8
    drwxr-xr-x. 2 cassandra cassandra 4096 Sep 11 14:02 .
    drwxr-xr-x. 5 cassandra cassandra 4096 Sep 11 14:02 ..

    /var/lib/cassandra/data/table_a/threat_sub_type:
    total 48
    drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 Nov  3 01:01 .
    drwxr-xr-x. 5 cassandra cassandra 4096 Sep 11 14:02 ..
    drwxr-xr-x. 2 cassandra cassandra 4096 Nov  3 01:01 backups
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra   43 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_sub_type-jb-3-CompressionInfo.db
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra  539 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_sub_type-jb-3-Data.db
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra   16 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_sub_type-jb-3-Filter.db
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra   35 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_sub_type-jb-3-Index.db
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra 4418 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_sub_type-jb-3-Statistics.db
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra  131 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_sub_type-jb-3-Summary.db
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra   79 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_sub_type-jb-3-TOC.txt
    drwxr-xr-x. 5 cassandra cassandra 4096 Nov 15 09:01 snapshots

    /var/lib/cassandra/data/table_a/threat_type:
    total 48
    drwxr-xr-x. 4 cassandra cassandra 4096 Nov  3 01:01 .
    drwxr-xr-x. 5 cassandra cassandra 4096 Sep 11 14:02 ..
    drwxr-xr-x. 2 cassandra cassandra 4096 Nov  3 01:01 backups
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra   43 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_type-jb-3-CompressionInfo.db
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra  739 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_type-jb-3-Data.db
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra   16 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_type-jb-3-Filter.db
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra   35 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_type-jb-3-Index.db
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra 4408 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_type-jb-3-Statistics.db
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra  131 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_type-jb-3-Summary.db
    -rw-r--r--. 3 cassandra cassandra   79 Nov  3 01:01 table_a-threat_type-jb-3-TOC.txt
    drwxr-xr-x. 6 cassandra cassandra 4096 Nov 15 09:01 snapshots
```

Comment: Replace `rm -rf` by `rm -rv` to see output.

Comment: Can you check returm from `rm` command? for example add after rm [ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "error rm command"

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov I listed the outputs.

Comment: `ls -all "$full_path"\*` should be `ls -all "$full_path"/*`

Comment: Eventually, for some reason it worked after I removed all double quotes from the script and it still works after I added all the double quotes back... Maybe there was a typo somewhere or the double quotes character was wrong...

Comment: Based on @tristan's comment, were you actually using `rm -rf "$fullpath"\*` previously?

Comment: @chepner No, I used what is in the body of the question. I fiddled around with the ls -all part.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your bash session has disabled pathname expansion, with `set -f`.

You can `set +f` in your script and check if it works.